# ftp command in one line for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I want to place my uploads folder from wordpress on a different server.

I read that in wp-config.php I had to add:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'folder where to move the files');
```

And in order to move the files to a different server I have to place the ftp argument instead of the folder.

However I keep getting an 'unable to create directory' error. I tested with ftptest.net to see if the ftp is working and this works correct.

This are my credentials I enter:

```
Host: <ip-adress>
Port: 21
Username: user@domain.com
Password: <password>
Protocal: Explicit FTP over TLS
```

I tried these 2 command with the same outcome of unable to create directory:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'ftp://user@domain.com:password@ip-adress:21');
define('UPLOADS', 'ftp://user:password@ip-adress:21');
```

Comment: `unable to create directory` -- did you check file permissions on the remote server? (Though I'm a bit skeptical about this)

Comment: @ppeterka , yes the file permissions are correct, I can login using winscp and create folders and upload files. (However I cannot find this files folders when login with scp to the public_html folder) Is it possible to replace ftp with scp?

Comment: I think it is not possible to upload file in remote server defined UPLOADS in wp-config.php. You can use filter to overwrite upload path and url in wordpress default uploads. add_filter( "upload_dir", "callback");

Comment: @user5200704, I looked into the add_filter. If I understand this correctly I can use this to run a function when another function is called? What I would want then is to let wordpress just upload the file (with all it's checks and creating a url) and then I just grab this file transfer it to my other server and delete the file on the wordpress server. However how do I get the info of the file which was just uploaded (i.e. path/name etc.)